# python How to connect password-less using jumpssh

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to do SSH through python script to host1 and then from there jump SSH to host2.
This can be achieved using `jumpssh` with below code:

```
>>> from jumpssh import SSHSession

# establish ssh connection between your local machine and the jump server
>>> gateway_session = SSHSession('gateway.example.com',
...                              'my_user_1', password='my_password_1').open()

# from jump server, establish connection with a remote server
>>> remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session('remote.example.com', 'my_user_2', password='my_password_2')
```

Now, here I am making connection to `remote.example.com` using the password.

I am not able to find a way, How we can connect to `remote.example.com` without password by simple `ssh remote.example.com` command passing once we inside hostname: `gateway.example.com`

When I am passing command: `ssh gateway.example.com` using jumpssh, I get error:

> Authentication failed, username and password required

Or is it possible with any other module in Python ?

Comment: ssh, in general,  is not possible without authentication. you have ot either use name/password or certificates

Comment: @Nullman: So, you mean to say, `ssh` commands are especially filtered for providing username/password mandatorily ?

Answer (score 0):

in general, ssh requires some form of authentication, either certificate(key) or name/password
according to the [api reference](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jumpssh/latest/jumpssh.pdf) you can use `private_key_file` as one of the parameters and it defaults to `~/.ssh/`
if you are unsure of what certificates are then you should [read up on it](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/), but in short you will need to create a certificate(key) pair, put the public one on the server you are trying to connect to and the private one either in `~/.ssh/` or pass the location to `jumpssh` using the `private_key_file` parameter

Comment: Thanks @Nullman. 
I have a peculiar case, where without any username/password and private_key_file path I have to do `ssh`.

Basically, I have to connect to ssh by simple `ssh <hostname>` as a command to test something.

I have an understanding, that authentication of my first ssh will be picked up while passing `ssh <hostname>` for the second time.

Am I missing something ?